# Typescript compilation error with Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-construction, typescript, npm

There are two typescript files:

- a module that implements the class Client

> 

```
export class Client {
```

- a main file that imports the module and creates an array of clients

> 

```
import c = module("client")
//...
class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.clients = new c.Client[];
```

Compiling the code seems to work fine. But when I try to run the generated javascript with nodejs, it complains that there is a syntax error:

```
this.clients = new ();
```

On the client side there's typescript code, too. But instead of modules, I'm using declaration paths and the --out compiler flag to compile everything into one .js file. Arrays in the client-side code are created without problems. In the javascript there's

```
this.arr = new Array();
```

So obviously the compiler just forgot to add specify that an Array is created with `new()`. I fixed the error manually by just inserting the missing part. But after a small change to the code and a new compilation, the same problem appeared again.
I'm using typescript version 0.8.3 and installed via npm. What can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your class Server defines clients to be an array of c.Client objects so it actually looks like this:

```
class Server {
    clients: c.Client[];
    constructor() {
        this.clients = new c.Client[];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this code compiled at all because it's actually a syntax error.  It doesn't compile for me.

You mixed up two different ways to declare an array: *new Array()* and *[]*.  Just change your line to this and you should be good to go:

```
this.clients = [];
```

Comment: interesting. on the client side the exact same code worked fine. Therefore i always assumed that the syntax was valid. Unfortunately the solution has either revealed or created a new problem. Well, that's not the scope of this question and I gladly accept your answer. +1 by me